# Subset over multiple numerical columns in R

Tags: r

I have 3 columns of data, each with a numeric distance value.

I successfully created a subset for each individual column to eliminate outliers with the following function:

```
newData <- subset(x, x < mean(x)+3*sd(x) & x > mean(x)-3*sd(x))
```

The problem is, that this creates three new vectors with different length, and I would like to run a t-test over the manipulated data.

How can I best create a subset of all three columns where data outside the condition is discarded?

Comment: `x[with(x, x < mean(x)+3*sd(x) & x > mean(x)-3*sd(x)), ]`?

Comment: Why are you removing outliers?

Comment: So you want to remove outliers and still have vectors of equal length?

Comment: I don't think your approach is well-grounded. If these three columns are independent sample sets, then the sample sizes shouldn't matter.  If they are not independent, then it's probably not a good idea to apply different criteria (i.e. the `sd` of each column) to different columns.  If you can tell us what your data set represents, we may be able to suggest a better approach to your actual problem.

Comment: I want to remove the outliers to guarantee that the later t-test is significant.
The data represents the distance to an object in 3 different tasks.

Comment: It worked with the following (Although it is quite long and sure not pretty coding, think the with-loop in the comments above does it prettier):
`SubsetDist <- subset(Dist, 
                      Dist$v1 < mean(Dist$v1)+3*sd(Dist$v1)
                     &Dist$v1 > mean(Dist$v1)-3*sd(Dist$v1)
                     
                     & Dist$v2 < mean(Dist$v2)+3*sd(Dist$v2) 
                     & Dist$v2 > mean(Dist$v2)-3*sd(Dist$v2) 
                     
                     & Dist$v3 < mean(Dist$v3)+3*sd(Dist$v3)
                     & Dist$v3 > mean(Dist$v3)-3*sd(Dist$v3))`